# Getting trouble making word game

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a word game something like below

[Word Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oLnl.png)

To achieve this I have created 2 views one for to show the tiles with letters on it, and targets to make a correct word out of those tiles.

It looks something like this 
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHxyR.png)

My plan is when the user touches the tile with word, it should move on to the target and when they touch it again it should come back to its original position.

```
func moveTheTile(tile: TileView) {
    print("Moving")

    for taget in targets {

        if taget.isTilePlaced == false {

            tile.center = taget.center
            taget.isTilePlaced = true

        }

    }
}
```

I have made this  delegate method from the tile to move but it is not moving to the target instead it is moving in the same view in which it contains.

I understand that I am not getting the location of the target compared with the main view but I don't know how to move to the targets.

Please try to explain me how to get this.